# Print letter by letter from a words-list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

list1 = ["chips"]
random_word = random.choice(list1)
user_guesses = 0
guess_limit = 10
index = 0
index_1 = random_word[index]

while user_guesses <= guess_limit:
    user_guess = input("enter your guess: ")   
    if index_1 == user_guess:
        print(index_1)
        index +=1
        user_guesses +=1
```

My question is that why doesn't the variable `index_1` move forward from `"c"` to `"h"` as it should because the word is **chips**. `index_1` stays only at `"c"`.

Comment: I think the user_guess should get updated every time in the loop right? or are you entering the correct value the first time?

Comment: yes, but the thing is that index_1 should move from "c" to "h" to "i" to "p" to "s" but now it only stays at "c"

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to re-ask for user input every iteration of the loop, so move `user_guess = input("enter your guess: ")` into the `while` loop

```
list1 = ["chips"]
random_word = random.choice(list1)
user_guesses = 0
guess_limit = 10
# (removed from here)
index = 0
index_1 = random_word[index]

while user_guesses <= guess_limit:
    user_guess = input("enter your guess: ")    #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if index_1 == user_guess:
        print(index_1)
        index +=1
        user_guesses +=1
```

Comment: yes, but the thing is that index_1 should move from "c" to "h" to "i" to "p" to "s" but now it only stays at "c"

Comment: You're incrementing index in the loop but index_1 also should be updated with the statement : index_1 = random_word[index] inside the loop

Comment: Thank you! @AmeyaR